# Reversed IN statement

Tags: php, sql

This is my query:

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FirstName IN ($input) OR Name IN ($input)";
```

$input looks like this:

```html
'input1', 'input2', 'input3'
```

When I search for "fischer" it finds a User with the Name "Fischer".
But when I search for "fisch" no entry is found.

Is there a way to "reverse" the IN-statement (WHERE $input IN (NAME)) so that I can check if any of the different inputs are part of any name?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: What `DBMS` are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the wildcard characters:

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE FirstName IN ('fisch%') OR Name IN ('fisch%');
```

will find `Fischer` - the `%` will act as a wildcard.

BTW: I do hope, that `$input` is not user-provided input: Else you would be very open to SQL injection attack.

Comment: `IN` is for comparing with literals, whereas `LIKE` allows wildcard comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `like` operator to search name .

```
  $sql= " SELECT * FROM Users 
WHERE FirstName LIKE '%$input' OR Name LIKE '%$input' OR FirstName LIKE '$input%' OR Name LIKE '$input%'";
```